# Double-free crash in lambda expression with clang 8

Tags: c++, clang

When moving a std::vector into a lambda expression and the lambda expression throws, I get a crash for a double-free on clang 8.0. Executables from other compilers like gcc or clang 7 are running without errors.

Am I doing something illegal in my code?

```
template<typename F>
void myExecute(F&& f)
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    try {
        std::vector<double> test = {0.0, 1.0};
        myExecute([v = std::move(test)]() {
            throw std::runtime_error("exception");
        });
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Try it in wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4MyA12gok4d7tFTc)

Comment: Looks like a bug.  7.0 and Head both work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found a matching bug report in llvm bugzilla:

https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41810

I'm now confident it's a compiler bug and not a problem in my code.